# How can I add more nodes in JaguarDB cluster?

Tags: database, nosql

I setup a JaguarDB cluster with two nodes. I want to add four more nodes in the cluster, so I added them in cluster.conf. But it seems that it is not working properly.

cluster.conf now has 4 nodes:

```
node1
node2
node3
node4
node5
node6
```

and restarted server.

The new nodes are not getting data records when I insert them.

Comment: Hi Joe, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions here are expected to show research effort, that is, what *you've* already done to solve your problem. We're happy to help, but only after you've tried yourself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

New nodes cannot be added manually in cluster.conf file. They have to be added with the addcluster command which allows you to add a number of nodes ( cluster) into the system.